# Strange dotted (not regular) line on some Android devices

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, border

We have problem with border on ex. layer. On some devices (Samsung Galaxy S II 4.1.2, Samsung Galaxy S+ 2.3, etc.) border is rendered properly  and on Nexus 4.3 and Samsung Galaxy Tab 4.0.4 instead of a solid line we got dashed (irregular) line.

We got this (see screenshot above) on Nexus 7 (4.3) - left line is dashed (wrong) and top line is solid (ok, but what is it? Antialias?). Does anyone know why this is happening? What are these lines? It's antialiasing problem?

For example (code from Stackoverflow's post):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <item>
       <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
           <solid android:color="#55111111" />
           <padding
               android:bottom="10dp"
               android:left="10dp"
               android:right="10dp"
               android:top="10dp" />
           <corners android:radius="5dp" />
       </shape>
   </item>
   <item>
       <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
           <padding
               android:bottom="5dp"
               android:left="5dp"
               android:right="5dp"
               android:top="5dp" />
           <solid android:color="#ff252525" />
       </shape>
   </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image]